Are amputated limbs and organs to be treated with the same care as a dead body?
In Judaism, when a person dies they are to be buried immediately.
My question is whether the same rule applies to organs and limbs of an individual who is still living.
If a Jew has an arm amputated or an organ removed, are they required to bury these pieces of themselves in a way which reflects burial practices for those who have died?
I know that there are statements in the Talmud which discuss the proper disposal of other pieces of your body. Specifically nail clippings.
The Talmud describes a man who buries their clippings as being righteous and one who burns them as being pious. Does this same or similar rule apply to app amputations of flesh and organs?
If a person does in fact bury their pieces, are they required to be in the same grave they will rest in once dead?
